# window.close() after submit will cancel the submission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just started with Chrome Extensions and when I use the following code everything works fine and the form is submitted. However, when I put `window.close();` behind the submit-part, the window closes, there is no error in the console but the form is not submitted correctly (i.e. no info shows). The same happens when I link to a new page after the submission. Is there a trick to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

```
function submit(e)
{
    var a = document.getElementsByName("title")[0];
    var errors = 0;
    if (a.value == "" | a.value == "Title") 
        {
            a.style.borderColor="red";
            errors +=1;
        }
    else 
        {
            a.style.borderColor="#dcdcdc";
        }

    if (errors == 0) 
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
        }

}
```

Comment: Submit give you a different page right? In that page, use JavaScript to trigger `window.close();`

Comment: Is there another way around that? The code that's executed is used by another site which would not appreciate a window.close(); - also, the popup doesn't really change URLs.

Comment: Well, you can use a `setTimeout()`, but depending on the server's response, we cannot reliably rely on it.

Comment: Sad to head - but thanks anyways - I guess I will have a second copy of the submission page. Thanks Kumar!

Comment: You can call me Praveen. :) Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [messages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and [content script injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to achieve this. Let's say page 1 contains the form you are submitting and page 2 is the page you submit to. Simply use a content script to inject code into page 2 that sends a message to your background page, which in turn triggers a window close on page 1. Your background page essentially acts as an operator between page 1 and page 2.